# Overlaying two geom_sf with same data sources but differents variables types in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile, r-sf

I want to overlay the plot 1 and 2 on the same plot.
They come from the same source and I want in the backgroung the plot 1 and add plot 2 with some transparency on top.

```
plot1= ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = toy,
          aes(geometry = geometry, fill = b),
          color = NA) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="#0099FF")

plot2= ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = toy ,
          aes(geometry = geometry, fill = a),
          color = NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(alpha("#CCCCCC",0), alpha("#990033",1)))
```

The work well independently, but I do no manage to combine them.
I tried the following things but got some errors

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = toy,
          aes(geometry = geometry, fill = b),
          color = NA) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="#0099FF") +
  geom_sf(data = toy ,
          aes(geometry = geometry, fill = a),
          color = NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(alpha("#CCCCCC",0), alpha("#990033",1)))
#> Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which
#> will replace the existing scale.
#> Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

To execute the code use :

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
```

The structure of my toy data is as follow :

```
structure(list(a = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), b = c(0.22798252850771, 
0.743008424993604, 0.388169342186302, 0.907995192101225, 0.953832301311195, 
0.40455531864427, 0.363415864063427, 0.805322113214061, 0.519045175751671, 
0.484226288506761), geometry = structure(list(structure(list(
    structure(c(1223540.00733145, 1223540.00733145, 1224040.00733145, 
    1224040.00733145, 1223540.00733145, 6046527.88033381, 6047027.88033381, 
    6047027.88033381, 6046527.88033381, 6046527.88033381), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(1224040.00733145, 1224040.00733145, 1224540.00733145, 
    1224540.00733145, 1224040.00733145, 6046527.88033381, 6047027.88033381, 
    6047027.88033381, 6046527.88033381, 6046527.88033381), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(1224540.00733145, 1224540.00733145, 1225040.00733145, 
    1225040.00733145, 1224540.00733145, 6046527.88033381, 6047027.88033381, 
    6047027.88033381, 6046527.88033381, 6046527.88033381), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(1225040.00733145, 1225040.00733145, 1225540.00733145, 
    1225540.00733145, 1225040.00733145, 6046527.88033381, 6047027.88033381, 
    6047027.88033381, 6046527.88033381, 6046527.88033381), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(1223540.00733145, 1223540.00733145, 1224040.00733145, 
    1224040.00733145, 1223540.00733145, 6047027.88033381, 6047527.88033381, 
    6047527.88033381, 6047027.88033381, 6047027.88033381), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(1224040.00733145, 1224040.00733145, 1224540.00733145, 
    1224540.00733145, 1224040.00733145, 6047027.88033381, 6047527.88033381, 
    6047527.88033381, 6047027.88033381, 6047027.88033381), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(1224540.00733145, 1224540.00733145, 1225040.00733145, 
    1225040.00733145, 1224540.00733145, 6047027.88033381, 6047527.88033381, 
    6047527.88033381, 6047027.88033381, 6047027.88033381), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(1225040.00733145, 1225040.00733145, 1225540.00733145, 
    1225540.00733145, 1225040.00733145, 6047027.88033381, 6047527.88033381, 
    6047527.88033381, 6047027.88033381, 6047027.88033381), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(1224040.00733145, 1224040.00733145, 1224540.00733145, 
    1224540.00733145, 1224040.00733145, 6047527.88033381, 6048027.88033381, 
    6048027.88033381, 6047527.88033381, 6047527.88033381), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(1224540.00733145, 1224540.00733145, 1225040.00733145, 
    1225040.00733145, 1224540.00733145, 6047527.88033381, 6048027.88033381, 
    6048027.88033381, 6047527.88033381, 6047527.88033381), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 1223540.00733145, 
ymin = 6046527.88033381, xmax = 1225540.00733145, ymax = 6048027.88033381
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = NA_character_, 
    wkt = "PROJCS[\"RGF_1993_Lambert_93\",\n    GEOGCS[\"GCS_RGF_1993\",\n        DATUM[\"Reseau_Geodesique_Francais_1993\",\n            SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],\n        UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295]],\n    PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP\"],\n    PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",700000.0],\n    PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",6600000.0],\n    PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",3.0],\n    PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",49.0],\n    PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",44.0],\n    PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",46.5],\n    UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(a = NA_integer_, 
b = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"
), class = "factor"), class = c("sf", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: You cannot use >1 scale per aesthetic in vanilla ggplot2. You might be interested in the {ggnewscale} package though.

Comment: Thanks @teunbrand but I tried following this tutorial using my data, but could'nt make it work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably due to the fact that we want to define two different `fill` scales for two different variables: `a` which is categorical, and `b` continuous. To do this, we can use the small (but very useful) `ggnewscale` library: https://eliocamp.github.io/ggnewscale/ which allows us to redefine a new scale *in the same plot*:

```
install.packages("ggnewscale")
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(data = toy) + 
   geom_sf(aes(geometry = geometry, fill = a)) + 
   scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FFFFFF00", "red")) +
   new_scale_fill() + 
   geom_sf(aes(geometry = geometry, fill = b, alpha = 0.5))
```

Notice the `new_scale_fill()` call before plotting the next layer, this allows us to use a different scale for this second layer.

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be to use the `color` option

It would make no sense to have multiple fill scales in the same place with some transparency, i think it would make it difficult to read. With color it makes it easy to read in my opinion

```
plot1 = ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = toy,
          aes(geometry = geometry, fill = b, color=a)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="#0099FF") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c(alpha("#CCCCCC",0), alpha("#990033",1)))
plot1
```

[image]

Comment: In my case, it actually does make sense. The backgroud variable "b" is at a much larger scale than the variable "a" so I'll have large blue squares with little red square on top.

Comment: Ok i see, my bad! i thought it would be a more similar example of the toy data you gave

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case you may want to consider as an alternative a bivariate map, than can be created with {bivariate}:

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(biscale)

# Prepare bivariate
toy2 <- bi_class(toy, x = a, y = b, style = "quantile", dim = 2)

map <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = toy2, aes(fill = bi_class),
          color = NA, show.legend = FALSE) +
  bi_scale_fill(pal = "GrPink", dim = 2) +
  # bi_theme() +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(r=80))

legend <- bi_legend(pal = "GrPink",
            dim = 2,
            xlab = "a ",
            ylab = "b ",
            size = 8)


ggdraw() +
  draw_plot(map, 0, 0, 1, 1) +
  draw_plot(legend, 0.75, .5, 0.3, 0.3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @dieghernan I didn't know about these maps, but I don't think it is adapted to my problem. The variable b is continuous so I would like a continuous scale. And it seems that we can only choose among a limited number of palettes in the arguments of function "bi_scale_fill" which is a pity because I would like to have only the polygons colored when a=1.

The point of the plot is to see how the variable a when a=1 is distributed on the map showing the distribution of variable b.